# webpack & babel-polyfill: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.array.map' in source directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, babel-polyfill

I'm facing this error when I execute `webpack`:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.array.map' in '/path/to/project/src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 1:0-39
```

`index.ts`:

```
console.log([1, 2, 3].map(x => x * x));
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',

  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: false,
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' },
          { loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.ts'
    ]
  }
};
```

I think it's very weird that the error is trying to resolve the module in `src/`, not `node_modules/`.

I tried removing `node_modules` and `package.json` and then `npm i`, but it didn't change the situation.

I also tried another way to use `@babel/polyfill` described [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill).

Setting `useBuiltIns` to `'entry'` just increased the number of similar errors. Setting it to `false` caused different errors.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6' in '/path/to/project/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/index.js 3:0-22
 @ multi @babel/polyfill ./src/index.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' in '/path/to/project/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/index.js 23:0-38
 @ multi @babel/polyfill ./src/index.ts
```

It seems `core-js` and `regenerator-runtime` should be installed in `node_modules/@babel/polyfill/`. Currently, there are only `index.js` and `noConflict.js` in the directory. Do I have to manually install those modules in this directory?

Comment: Have you included @babel/polyfill ?

Comment: No, because when useBuiltIns is 'usage' @babel/polyfill should not be included in source (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill)

Comment: Why are you using ts-loader? babel has built in support for TS as of v7. Did you try installing core-js the docs say you may need to - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins?

Comment: I symbolic-linked node_module/core-js to node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/core-js and src/core-js and it seems accessible, but the errors still occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following in your `resolve`s -

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.ts',
      '.js' // add this
    ]
  }
```